# texdoc finds no results for any package

Tags: emacs, documentation, texdoc

Whatever package name I use when invoking `texdoc`, I get no results. Which seems to indicate that something is missing from the setup. I made sure that several documentation packages are installed. Here's a transcript to make it more concrete:

```
$ sudo yum install texlive-commath-doc
<yum noise snipped>
Running Transaction
  Installing : 2:texlive-commath-doc-svn15878.0.3-20.fc18.noarch            1/1 
  Verifying  : 2:texlive-commath-doc-svn15878.0.3-20.fc18.noarch            1/1 

Installed:
  texlive-commath-doc.noarch 2:svn15878.0.3-20.fc18                             

Complete!
$ texdoc commath
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/lsR19748.tmp/ls-R: Permission denied
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/lsR19748.tmp/ls-r: Permission denied
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/lsR19748.tmp/ls-R: Permission denied
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/lsR19748.tmp/ls-r: Permission denied
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/lsR19748.tmp/aliases: Permission denied
Sorry, no documentation found for commath.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

What do I need to specify / install to make it work? Is there maybe an alternative?

As an aside, I'd be more interested in a solution which works with Emacs (man or info pages would be great).

Comment: It is a permissions problem as the message says. Either something is very screwed up with your system or something is very screwed up with Fedora/Red Hat's packaging. If the latter, you'd be best asking on their forums. Are you positive that `yum` is not giving warnings or errors? It should (almost certainly) not be looking for `lsR19748.tmp`. Does that directory even exist?

Comment: @cfr Nope, it isn't. The documentation isn't there. That directory was created by ESS as far as I can tell. I also ran `texdoc` as root, that didn't change anything (except the "Permission denied" message went away). Yum did install that package, I can find its content and look inside etc.

Comment: PS. The documentation appears to be installed in `/usr/share/doc/`.

Comment: I really hesitate to suggest anything since I'm not familiar with the packaging. If you wish to continue using packages from your distro, I recommend asking on their forums. An alternative would be installing TeX Live from upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason, or at least I could fix it, following this thread: http://www.forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=301163

What I found is that search.tlu had code that wouldn't create a database and thus `texdoc` wouldn't search at all. Below is the relevant code with my edits:

```
-- populate the doc_roots filename databases
function init_texdocs_database()
    doc_roots = {}
    local sep = (os.type == 'windows') and ';' or ':'
    local kpse_texdocs = kpse.expand_var("$TEXDOCS")
    -- expand the path and turn it into a lua list
    local raw_doc_roots = string.explode(kpse.expand_braces(kpse_texdocs), sep)
    local max = #raw_doc_roots + 1
    for j, dir in ipairs(raw_doc_roots) do
        local i = max - j
        local n
        local path, db
        -- get path, !! and // values
        dir, n = string.gsub(dir, '//$', '')
        local recursion_allowed = (n == 1)
        local path, n = string.gsub (dir, '^!!', '')
        local index_mandatory = (n == 1)
        deb_print('texdocs', string.format(
            'texdocs[%d] = %s (index_mandatory=%s, recursion_allowed=%s)',
            i, path, tostring(index_mandatory), tostring(recursion_allowed)))
        -- decide if we should use a ls-R index, the filesystem, or do nothing
        local root, shift = lsr_root(path)
        if root and shift and recursion_allowed then
            deb_print('texdocs', string.format(
                'texdocs[%d] using index: %s (shift=%s)', i, root, shift))
            db = init_lsr_db(root, shift)
        elseif not index_mandatory and lfs.isdir(path) then
            deb_print('texdocs', string.format(
                'texdocs[%d] using filesystem search', i))
            -- db = init_tree_db(path, recursion_allowed)
            -- Above was the original code, but it could never work because
            -- if you can't recurse on subdirectories of the documentation
            -- directory, there's no way you can find any files at all.
            -- I've no idea why this was the way it was.
            db = init_tree_db(path, true)
        end
        -- register this in docroots
        doc_roots[i] = { path = path, db = db }
    end
end
```